# Jitpack Gitlab Private Repository Trial No read access to repo

Tags: android, repository, gitlab, private, jitpack

I am trying out the 14 days trial of `Jitpack.io` so that I can use my Android Libraries on gitlab through `gradle` in my production apps.

So what I basically have:
2 Android apps on GitLab
2 Android Libraries on GitLab

I am currently importing them by (settings.gradle):

```
include ':app',':library'
project(':library').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'some_/long/path')
```

build.gradle:

```
    implementation project(':library')
```

Which is obviously quite troublesome. So I did:

1. I followed the 'setup' part on [the original docs](https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/)
2. I followed the 'Gitlab' part on [the original docs](https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/)

I think everything was quite well setup because I saw my repositories at the [homepage](https://jitpack.io/) on the left hand side so I went to the [private page](https://jitpack.io/private) to test out if I could get it to work. I also obviously did what was told in the private section.

So my files looked like this:

gradle.properties (nothing, basically that line):

```
authToken=my_super_secret_token_generated_by_gitlab
```

project build.gradle:

```
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
        credentials { username authToken }
    }
```

And then my build.gradle in my app:

```
implementation 'com.gitlab.organization:library:master'
```

But then I get a strange unauthorized error, I don't know why. My Access Token has API access and when I fill in the token in Jitpack it also shows a green checkmark. See my error below:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.gitlab.organization:library:master.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.gitlab.organization:library:master.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/gitlab/organization/library/master/library-master.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/gitlab/organization/library/master/library-master/libary-master.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Does someone has any idea why it is unauthorized? I got to say `library` is in a subgroup, so I have tried many other ways to try to resolve it but It did not really help.

Comment: Hi @Karl-John Chow, I am trying to distribute my android libraries through Jitpack. I am using GitLab. Please provide me the detailed steps to publish the library to Jitpack. I didn't see any detailed documentation for Gitlab.

Comment: @SKK https://jitpack.io/private this helps you

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me that how can I create personal libs. I try to do but getting nothing

Answer (score 3):

The "authToken" need to be generated by jitpack user profile and not from gitlab